# ASP.NET Razor HTML - Change the background color of a tables row depending on a value

Tags: asp.net, html, razor

I am developing a website using ASP.NET c# using razor view engine. I am using a for loop to display  rows from a database and display it in a html table. each row contains a variable called "requestStatus".  the request status is either "approved", "rejected" or Pending. Is there a way i can change the bg color of the table row based on the requeststatus , so for example if the requeststatus is "pending" set the table row to yellow, if the request status is "approved" set table row bgcolor to green ?

any help would be much great !

the code i use display the table is below

```
 <fieldset>
            <legend>Your Leave Requests</legend>
            <table border="1" width="100%"> 



            <tr bgcolor="grey">
            <th>Description</th> 
            <th>Leave Type</th> 
            <th>Start Date</th> 
            <th>End Date</th> 
            <th>Total days leave requested</th> 
            <th>Request Status</th> 
            </tr>

           @foreach(var rows2 in rows1){


            <tr>

            <th>@rows2.description</th>
            <th>@rows2.leaveType</th> 
            <th>@rows2.startDate.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")</th> 
            <th>@rows2.endDate.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")</th> 
            <th>@rows2.totalDays</th> 
            <th>@rows2.requestStatus</th> 
            </tr>
              }  
            </table>

            </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use the requestStatus as you class name and assign styles as appropiate:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .grey {
        background-color:grey;
    }
    .approved {
        background-color:green;
    }
    .rejected {
        background-color:red;
    }
    .pending {
        background-color:lime;
    }
</style>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Your Leave Requests</legend>
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr class="grey">
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Leave Type</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Total days leave requested</th>
            <th>Request Status</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var rows2 in rows1)
        {

            <tr class="@rows2.requestStatus">
                <td>@rows2.description</th>
                <td>@rows2.leaveType</th>
                <td>@rows2.startDate.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")</th>
                <td>@rows2.endDate.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")</th>
                <td>@rows2.totalDays</th>
                <td>@rows2.requestStatus</th>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi skyblues, your answer worked perfectly , i would of never figured it out by myself , thanks both of you for your help

Comment: Yeah, even I agree :) this is the easiest approach.  Only flip side to this is if you change your status text you will need to remember to change your css as well.  Our practice has always been to keep your css class names loosely coupled to your code values.

Comment: Simple and elegant!

Answer (score 4):

Your razor should look something like this:

    
            Your Leave Requests

```
        <tr bgcolor="grey">
        <th>Description</th> 
        <th>Leave Type</th> 
        <th>Start Date</th> 
        <th>End Date</th> 
        <th>Total days leave requested</th> 
        <th>Request Status</th> 
        </tr>

       @foreach (var rows2 in rows1)
       {
           @
           {
               var statusClass = "colorA";

               if (rows2.requestStatus == "pending")
               {
                   statusClass = "colorB";
               }

           }

       <tr class="@statusClass">

        <td>@rows2.description</td>
        <td>@rows2.leaveType</td> 
        <td>@rows2.startDate.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")</td> 
        <td>@rows2.endDate.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")</td> 
        <td>@rows2.totalDays</td> 
        <td>@rows2.requestStatus</td> 
        </tr>
          }  
        </table>

        </fieldset>
```

Then you need to have some classes specified in your css:

```
.colorA {background-color: red}
.colorB {background-color: green}
```

That answers your question based on your code.  A better practice, imo, would be to put a statusClass property on your row2 object model.  Then, in your logic, set this based on whatever logic you need and, instead of having that "if" statement and variable, just set the tr class directly, like this:

```
<tr class="@row2.statusClass">
```

Comment: hi jason , thanks for reply, if have add the following code that you suggested, the table is displayed but the rows bgcolor do not change they are just plain white

Comment: @foreach(var rows2 in rows1){
                   
                   
                   
                   var statusClass="colorA";

                   if(rows2.requstStatus="pending"){
                       
                       statusClass = "colorB";
                   }
                   
                <tr class="statusClass" >

Comment: you added the classes to your css and your css is referenced correctly?

Comment: I just noticed that the <th> in the <tr> with statusClass should be <td> instead.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/fE4Ec/) of what it should look like.  I added a row with <tr><th></th></tr> so you can see how that doesn't work (the last row).  The first two rows use the <td> element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change row color without define CSS class you can do this:

```
    <fieldset>
    <table border="1" width="100%">
      <tr bgcolor="grey">
        <th>Description</th> 
        <th>Leave Type</th> 
        <th>Start Date</th> 
        <th>End Date</th> 
        <th>Total days leave requested</th> 
        <th>Request Status</th>
      </tr>

   @foreach (var rows2 in rows1)
   {

        if(rows2.requestStatus == "pending"){
        <tr style="background:#faf0bc">
          <td>@rows2.description</td>
          <td>@rows2.leaveType</td> 
          <td>@rows2.startDate.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")</td> 
          <td>@rows2.endDate.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")</td> 
          <td>@rows2.totalDays</td> 
          <td>@rows2.requestStatus</td> 
        </tr>
      }  
       else{
     <tr style="background:#fef7d0">
       <td>@rows2.description</td>
       <td>@rows2.leaveType</td> 
       <td>@rows2.startDate.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")</td> 
       <td>@rows2.endDate.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")</td> 
       <td>@rows2.totalDays</td> 
       <td>@rows2.requestStatus</td> 
    </tr>
       }
   }

     </table>

    </fieldset>
```